# Trouble including graphics from csv file into Pgftable, commands are dissapearing (local maybe?)

Tags: tables, macros, pgfplots, errors, pgfplotstable

I've been trying to add eps graphics with the filename in a csv file. Take a look at the CSV to get an idea of what I mean: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao9if7HTdeaPdGowdXJXbURJQWVmVTdDUVRaYTdldXc#gid=0

So far, I've managed to get LaTeX to spit out this much:[image: Table of Reagents]

I'm trying to place figures (with compound eps and name) for each compound in the Reagent column. So far I've created a new column in Pgfplotstable and I'm trying to include values from the name and structure column of my csv file.

I'm pretty confused at this point, so I started trying to create a new command for every image which I would later call in the figure (\cmpi->compound 1 name, \structurei->compound 1 structure, \cmpii->compound 2 name, \structureii->compound 2 structure). I can't get that set up because the commands are lost after another call to defineCompound. There is probably a better way to create the in-table figures, but I am lost at this point.

The first `\typeout{TESTING: \cmpi, \structurei}` works and prints `TESTING: (R)-(-)carvone, ../chemicals/(r)-(-)-carvone.eps`, but the second fails due to "Undefined control sequence"

[image: errors]

Any help at this point would be appreciated. I've just started using LaTeX and it's been a pretty rough journey so far.

I'm hoping to finally be able to have all of my compounds in one csv file and just be able to select which ones I would like based on which experiment I'm performing.

My LaTeX is:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[left=.75in,right=.75in,top=.75in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage[journal=rsc]{chemstyle}



\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps,1]{
  label={Step~\arabic*},
  leftmargin=*,
  align=left,
  labelsep=10mm,
}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\newcommand\defineCompound[3]{%
    \typeout{#1}
    \typeout{#2}
    \typeout{#3}
    \global\expandafter\newcommand\csname cmp#1\endcsname{#2}
    \global\expandafter\newcommand\csname structure#1\endcsname{#3}
    \typeout{TESTING: \cmpi, \structurei}
}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\section{Introduction}
\newcommand{\expnum}{14}
\newcommand{\exptitle}{Conversion of Carvone to Carvacrol: Multiweek Experiment Part 1}
\input{../common/intro.tex}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \caption{Conversion of (R)-(-)Carvone to Carvacrol by Sulfuric Acid and Heat.}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../reactions/(r)-(-)-carvone-to-carvacrol.eps}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \caption{Balanced Equation.}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../reactions/2.eps}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\section{Table of Reagents}
\begin{center}
  \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{../common/reagents.csv}\loadedtable
  \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/assign/.code={%
      \getthisrow{name}\name
      \getthisrow{structure}\structure
      \FPeval{\result}{clip(\pgfplotstablerow + 1)}
      \edef\entry{\romannumeral\result}
      \defineCompound{\entry}{\name}{\structure}
      \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
    }]{reagent}\loadedtable
  \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    string type,
    begin table=\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth},
    end table=\end{tabularx},
    columns={reagent,mw,bp,mp,density},
    %columns/name/.style={column name=Name, column type={|c}},
    columns/reagent/.style={
      column name=Reagent,
      column type={l},
      postproc cell content/.code={
        \message{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}}
        \message{\cmpi}
        %\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
      },
    },
    columns/mw/.style={column name={Molecular Weight (\si[per-mode=symbol]{\gram\per\mol})}, column type={X}},
    columns/bp/.style={column name=Boiling Point (\si{\celsius}), column type={l}},
    columns/mp/.style={column name=Melting Point (\si{\celsius}), column type={l}},
    columns/density/.style={column name=Density (g/mol), column type={X}},
    every nth row={1}{before row=\midrule},
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    ]\loadedtable
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome at tex.sx. If you are doing first steps with LaTeX -- are you sure that this is good first use-case? It sounds to be highly advanced to me...

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've blown up a simple use to a really complex one. I'm going to try to simplify the problem so I can attack it a little easier.

Answer (score 2):

I hope that I am answering the right question here... from what I understand you have a column of sorts "filename" and instead of just typesetting the file name, you want to include the associated graphics file by means of `\includegraphics`, right? If this assumption is wrong, I'd ask you to clean up your example and rephrase the question accordingly.

*If* my understanding is correct, then the following might prove helpful:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
  \pgfplotstableread{
filename X
PP-figure0.pdf 1
PP-figure1.pdf 2
PP-figure2.pdf 3
}\loadedtable

  \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/filename/.style={
      column name=Reagent,
      column type={l},
      assign cell content/.code={%
          \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\includegraphics{##1}}%
      },
    },
    ]\loadedtable

\end{document}
```

I have generated a small minimal example on my own. It uses `assign cell content` since this step is not a preprocessing step; it is *the* step as such.

It might benefit from some vertical alignment, but before I (or someone else) jumps onto it, you should clarify if this is what you wanted.

---

For the records: I generated the graphics files using `pdflatex -shell-escape PP` on the following file

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize


\begin{document}

\tikz \draw[left color=red, right color=white] (0,0) circle (10pt);
\tikz \draw[left color=blue, right color=white] (0,0) circle (10pt);
\tikz \draw[left color=black, right color=white] (0,0) circle (10pt);
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Include graphics works right up until I need to add the name of the compound below the graphic in the table. I can't figure out how to access the name of the compound and include the graphics in the same cell, which is why my example is getting overly complex.

Comment: Ah, I see. Could you modify your example such that it compiles out-of-the box (in particular, includes the table + its column names) with as few dependencies as possible?